# Kinesis Analytics Tumbling Window to Group Common Events Together

Tags: mysql, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I have a use case where Kinesis is ingesting events from video streams (each video stream has a unique ID), however the data broken up and is arriving out of order.

For example:

```
VideoId1 {}
VideoId2 {}
VideoId2 {}
VideoId1 {}
VideoId1 {}
```

What I'm trying to do here is use tumbling windows to weave the video stream events together into one continuous, chronological segment. For example:

```
VideoId1-> [Event1, Event2, Event3, etc] (from the 1 minute window)
VideoId2-> [Event1, Event2, Event3, etc] (from the 1 minute window)
```

However, I'm finding this difficult to do in Kinesis Analytics. It seems tumbling windows require a group by clause, which I don't require here. Any pointers or advice here would be very helpful. Perhaps Analytics isn't the right tool.